# How to make scroll bar appear only when the window size gets increased

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, scrollbar

I have a UI which consists of drag and drop . I have a tree structure on left side . I have to drag an item from the tree structure from left side and drop it as a composite to my right side. So when the number of composites increases on my right side then scroll bar should appear. But my scroll bars are visible before the number of composites are getting increased. Even if I set showScollbar(false) even then I have the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For example your right side div in which you drop the element have id right like

```
<div id="right">
```

then write in css file as follows

```
#right { overflow: hidden;}
#right:hover {overflow: auto;}
```